# Update loading bar within jQuery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure this must be a common problem, but after much searching I can't find an answer.
I have a twitter-bootstrap loading bar that I would like to update after each stage of a calculation is completed.

Here is the function for updating the loading bar:

```
var lb = $('#loading-bar');
var lbc = 0;

function increment_loading_bar(pc) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        lbc = lbc + pc;
        lb.width(lbc+"%");;
    }, 1);
}
```

And the calls to update the bar are within a .each() loop

```
var inc = 100/array.length();

$.each(array,function(index,element){
    increment_loading_bar(inc/2);

    //
    //Gnarly processing ....
    //

    increment_loading_bar(inc/2);
}
```

However, this only updates after all the processing has finished. How can the redraw of the bar be forced as the code is executed?

Many thanks!

Comment: im missing some code, because you are still calculating width from var inc which is not changing in your samples

Comment: inc is the increment rather than the absolute value. The variable lbc stores the current percentage width of the bar, and is incremented by pc each time increment_loading_bar is called.

Comment: well you know whats the length you want to finish, simple store array.length, and each iteration update progress bar to (iteration/array.length) and remove that timeout, and also you should Math.round the value for width

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing. However, the bar does not update until /all/ processing has been done. With or without setTimeout does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: try to debug it, log every lbc value on each call via console.log and check it in your console

Comment: The values of lbc update as expected and at the right time. As I said in my question, the /redraw/ needs to be forced as the code is executed.

Comment: What exactly are you "processing" there? Are you doing CPU Heavy operations in the DOM Tree?

Comment: There's a lot of graphing commands (using flot) in there that take a fair bit of time. These seem to take up about 63% of the execution time. Another 25% ish is taken up by cssHooks in jquery according to the chrome JS profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I said in my question, the /redraw/ needs to be forced as the code is executed

To my knowledge, you can only indirectly force the Redraw by pausing your Process once in a while. 
For example like this:

```
var inc = 100/array.length();
var processQueue = array;
var currentIndex;

setTimeout(runProcess, 5);

function runProcess() {
   var element = processQueue[currentIndex];

   // Process the element here
   // ....

   increment_loading_bar(inc);

   currentIndex++;

   if (currentIndex < processQueue.length) {
      setTimeout(runProcess, 5);
   } else {
      // processing has finished
   }
}
```

This way you give the browser some time (5ms in this example) between each step to redraw the loading bar.

Comment: Should the setTimeout be retained in the increase_loading_bar function as well? I'm probably being a bit dense here, but why does it not work with the setTimeout only in the increment_loading_bar?

Comment: No you don't need that one. I'm not quite sure what's the reason. Maybe a browser optimization thing to redraw only once javascript is done executing or so.

Comment: This almost works! Although the bar is updating when it should, the css animation / transition is very jerky when the width is changed. I've tried putting some setTimeouts around the place to allow the browser to update properly, but this hasn't worked.

Comment: You probably will need to increase the pause between each process-step. Increase the Timeout from 5ms to 100ms or so. That should work. Or you disable the css animation altogether.